# access denied when I use xDocument.Load() file from PickSingleFileAsync()

Tags: linq-to-xml

I'm writing universal apps in WP 8.1. I want to Load an XML using FilePicker. However I got an error Access to the path 'D:\questions.xml' is denied

Here my code

```
        var filename = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (filename == null)
        {
            TestDataFileName = "";
        }
        else
        {
            var _Content = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(filename);

            //TestDataPath = filename.Path;
            TestDataFileName = _Content;


            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename.Path); //Error occurred
```

Thank you very much.

```
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the user which you are currently logged-in, doesn't have enough permission to access the file at location

> "D:\questions.xml"

Try giving the read-write permissions to specified location and see.

I hope this will work.
Thank you